# Finding duplicate values in multiple colums in a SQL table and count

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I have the following table structure:

```
id num1 num2 num3  ...
 1    1    2    3
 2    1    3    2
 3    1    2    3
 .
 .
 .
```

I use the following command to display the duplicates and the counts:

```
SELECT COUNT(num1), num1, num2, num3 
FROM table 
GROUP BY num1, num2, num3 
HAVING (COUNT(num1) > 1) AND (COUNT(num2) > 1) AND (COUNT(num3) > 1)
```

This command gives me a count of 2. I would like to know how the second line could also be counted as a dublicate.

Comment: Are there only 3 num columns in the table?

Comment: Yes and a few other string colums

Comment: Do you consider duplicate rows that have all 3 numbers in any of the 3 columns?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Then check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the scalar functions [`MIN()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#min_scalar) and [`MAX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar) to get the 3 integer values of each row in ascending order, so that you can create a unique triplet to group by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count,
       MIN(num1, num2, num3) num_1,
       num1 + num2 + num3 - MIN(num1, num2, num3) - MAX(num1, num2, num3) num_2,
       MAX(num1, num2, num3) num_3
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY num_1, num_2, num_3 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=194e6459125b89961212be3871540eef).

Comment: That does exactly what it should. Thank you.
Does that also work with CHAR instead of Int? I have a similar use case for names of people

Comment: @MikaBA no, this works only for numeric values.

Comment: do you have another idea for char or should i ask a new question?
Sorry for the circumstances. These are both topics that have stolen me a few hours.

Comment: @MikaBA the requirement or the solution is different for non-numeric values, so you should ask a new question where you explain what you want with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

changing operator to OR will return what you want

```
SELECT COUNT(num1), num1, num2, num3 
FROM table 
GROUP BY num1, num2, num3 
HAVING (COUNT(num1) > 1) OR (COUNT(num2) > 1) OR (COUNT(num3) > 1)
```

Comment: the result is the same as before